# What is the collective meaning of "Until Suddenly"

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning

I am trying to understand the collective meaning of - until suddenly. I tried a lot on google but did not find any. I know the meaning of suddenly but what is - until suddenly?

Sentence is - he ran behind the monster deep into the forest, **until suddenly** the sound of the monster's footsteps stopped

source of this sentence is a story in this video: https://youtu.be/4bvGETtvJ-k?t=153

Comment: I watched about 30 seconds of this video, and I saw many grammatical errors and many instances of awkward, unidiomatic phrasing. Please avoid this source if your goal is to learn proper English. Also, please don't rely on the internet for examples of grammatical English; most of what is posted has never been edited, and errors abound.

Comment: I indeed listen for good English. I am just a beginner so could not figure out grammatical mistakes. Would you like to suggest any better source?

Answer (score 2):

The two words each have a different meaning and function.

"Until" is a conjunction.  It links the two clauses.  The second clause tells when he stopped running. ("he ran ... until ...")

"Suddenly" is an adverb.  It tells us how the footsteps stopped.  The stopped without warning. They did not get quieter and fade away.  You could omit "suddenly" and the sentence would still be grammatical. You could also move the adverb  "... until the sound ... stopped suddenly."

Answer (score 0):

*Until* is a preposition; it means *up to (the point in time or the event mentioned)*. The phrase *until suddenly* is awkward, and it borders on being redundant.

Here are some grammatical alternatives:
---- He ran behind the monster, deep into the forest, until the sound of the monster's footsteps stopped.
---- He ran behind the monster, deep into the forest, until he could no longer hear the the monster's footsteps.
---- He ran behind the monster, deep into the forest; suddenly the sound of the monster's footsteps stopped. (Note that I used a semicolon to link these two independent clauses, whereas the original used a comma to link an independent clause and a dependent clause.)

Comment: I beg to differ: "until suddenly" and "until finally" have very different meanings. There is nothing redundant about specifying the amount of time it takes for something to change.